# What's label:metric:function in PromqQL?

Tags: promql, prometheus-operator

I am reading kube-prometheus, https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus and came across a PromQL in a Prometheus rule file which I am having hard time understanding.

```
sum(namespace:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores:sum)
```

in here https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/prometheus-rules.yaml#L673

But similarly this

```
sum(container:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores:sum)
```

doesn't return anything where 'container' is just a label like 'namespace'

This is how the instant vector looks like for "kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores"

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="kube-controller-manager",instance="172.17.0.7:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="kube-system",node="minikube",pod="kube-controller-manager-minikube"}
```

Can someone explain to me how's this working and were in the PromQL documentation it's mentioned to do this kind of query?

Can we do a query like this "label:metric:function"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot query like, "label:metric:function".

`namespace:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores:sum` is nothing but a name of a Prometheus [rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) which is define in [here](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/prometheus-rules.yaml#L119-L129).

```c
    - expr: |
        sum by (namespace) (
            sum by (namespace, pod) (
                max by (namespace, pod, container) (
                    kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{job="kube-state-metrics"}
                ) * on(namespace, pod) group_left() max by (namespace, pod) (
                    kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1
                )
            )
        )
      record: namespace:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes:sum
```

So, whenever you create a new rule, Prometheus creates a new time series metric named after the rule name (i.e. `namespace:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes:sum`).

If you want to query something like `container:kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores:sum`, you need to record a rule first by this name.

NB:

> Recording rules should be of the general form level:metric:operations. level represents the aggregation level and labels of the rule output. metric is the metric name and should be unchanged other than stripping _total off counters when using rate() or irate(). operations is a list of operations that were applied to the metric, newest operation first.

Comment: thanks a lot, @kamol-hasan for this. My bad that I didn't search it within the file.